# How to see key count of matching pattern in Azure Redis Cache Console

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I want to just see the total number of keys available in Azure Redis cache that matches the given pattern. I tried the following command it is showing the count after displaying all the keys (which caused server load), But I need only the count.

```
>SCAN 0 COUNT 10000000 MATCH "{UID}*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except command `SCAN`, the command [`KEYS pattern`](https://redis.io/commands/keys) can return the same result as your current command `SCAN 0 COUNT 10000000 MATCH "{UID}*"`.

However, for your real needs to get the number of keys matching a pattern, there is an issue [`add COUNT command`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/32) from the Redis offical GitHub repo which had answered by the author `antirez` for you, as the content below.

> Hi, KEYS is only intended for debugging since it is O(N) and performs a full keyspace scan. COUNT has the same problem but without the excuse of being useful for debugging... (since you can simply use redis-cli keys ... | grep ...). So feature not accepted. Thanks for your interest.

So you can not directly get the count of `KEYS pattern`, but there are some possible solutions for you.

1. Count the keys return from command `KEYS pattern` in your programming language for the small number of keys with a pattern, like doing `redis-cli KEYS "{UID}*" | wc -l` on the host server of Redis.
2. To use the command [`EVAL script numkeys key \[key ...\] arg \[arg ...\]`](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to run a Lua script to count the keys with pattern, there are two scripts you can try.

   2.1. Script 1

   ```
   return #redis.call("keys", "{UID}*")
   ```

   2.2. Script 2

   ```
   return table.getn(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]))
   ```

   The completed command in `redis-cli` is `EVAL "return table.getn(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]))" 0 {UID}*`